# Next Button like the Navigation Controller's Back Button in IB - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

I'm sure there was preconfigured **Next** button in *Interface Builder* that looked like the **< Back** button, but I don't see it anymore. Is there another way to show a custom icon **AND** text that look like the back button in Interface Builder or can this only be done in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create UIButton object, set an image with title for it, and then create your UIBarButtonItem with it:

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .System)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "YourImage"), forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitle("YourTitle", forState: .Normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    self.leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

To add an action:

```
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tappedAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

where self.someAction is

```
func tappedAction() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no preconfigured Next button. 
You have to create a bar button item object and set it as right bar button item of your navigation item bar.

```
let homeButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "LeftButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "")

let logButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "RigthButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "")

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = homeButton
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton
```